# In bash, how to make "set -x" print lines to stdout instead of stderr?

Tags: bash

I would like a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it, just like what `set -x` does, but I do not want it to be printed do stderr.

I know I could redirect stderr to stdout, like `exec 2>&1`, but that will redirect all of stderr (and `exec` would be printed to stderr). I still want actual error messages to be printed to stderr, so redirecting everything is not what I want.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. It's built into bash. I don't see in what sense this would be useful, but if you can describe a good usecase, you could post a feature request at the [bash project page](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/bash/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `BASH_XTRACEFD`.

```
BASH_XTRACEFD=1
```

Comment: It should be noted that this variable was added in Bash 4.1, cf. https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES